# Making a data type an instance of Show in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, tree, instance, show

I need to make the following data type an instance of `Show`:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a
```

I'm fairly new at this, but to start with, I interpreted this declaration as

"We have made a new type called Tree, which is parameterized with types a and b. A tree can be one of two things: a Branch which holds a piece of data of type b, plus two more Trees, or a Leaf which holds a data item of type a."

Now, I need to make a way to "Show" it nicely (nested branches, etc.), without using `deriving`. So far, I have only been writing functions in a module Main and loading/playing with them in an interpreter window, so I haven't actually done things with constructors, etc, before. Nevertheless, I figured I could just start off by declaring the tree data type within my file, as shown at the beginning of the question, and go from there.

As I messed around with "Show" without much success, I thought maybe I needed to define a small component of the tree and how to "Show" it first, before trying to work with the whole tree:

```
data Leaf a = Leaf a

instance Show (Leaf a) where
show (Leaf a) = ???
```

I tried a number of things in the ??? spot, such as "a", just a by itself, putStrLn, etc., but none are printing out the value of a when I say something like

```
>show (Leaf 3)
```

In fact, I have in many cases encountered this, which probably means I am not locating things right:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `show'
    It could refer to either `Main.show', defined at a2.hs:125:1
                          or `Prelude.show',
                             imported from `Prelude' at a2.hs:2:8-11
                             (and originally defined in `GHC.Show')
```

...which I addressed by calling "Main.show," which of course doesn't work.

I guess the question is, where do I go with all this...or maybe just, "How can I fix the Leaf "Show" utility so that I can figure out how to extend it?" (assuming I have to define it first...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to start like that:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
    show (Leaf x) = show x
    show (Branch p l r) = ???
```

In order to `show` a `Tree a b` you have to first be able to `show` `a`s and `b`s. That's what the `(Show a, Show b) =>` part does, it specifies the preconditions you require for your instance to work.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest answer would be to automatically derive a `Show` instance:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a deriving Show
```

But let's say that doesn't give you output of the form you want. If you want to define your own `Show` instance, you'd do something like:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
    show (Leaf a) = "Leaf " ++ (show a)
    show (Branch b l r) = "Branch " ++ (show b) ++ " { " ++ l ++ ", " ++ r " }"
```

The way you might read that first line is, "given `a` and `b` are both instances of the `Show` typeclass, `Tree a b` is also an instance of the `Show` typeclass..."

By the way, **indentation is important**. It may have gotten mangled in the snippet you pasted, but you must indent the `show` function definitions under the `instance` declaration.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a minor hint: By writing

```
 instance Show (Leaf a) where
 show (Leaf a) = ???
```

what you *actually* did was define an *empty* `Show` instance, followed by a top-level `show` function. This is why you get the "ambiguous `show`" error; you've defined a new `show` function, whose name clashes with the existing one.

What you *meant* to say was

```
 instance Show (Leaf a) where
   show (Leaf a) = ???
```

Note how the second line is indented now. This means you're redefining the existing `show` method, as you presumably intended.

Answer (score 2):

Your data-type is a perfect candidate for `deriving Show`.

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a deriving Show
```

That will automatically generate the Show instance for you.

If you want to create a manual instance of Show, here's the thought process.

First, the basic skeleton:

```
instance Show (Tree a b) where
   -- show :: Tree a b -> String
   show (Branch b ltree rtree) = {- some string -}
   show (Leaf a) = {- some string -}
```

Now we know that we'll need some way to show values of type `a` and `b` as strings.  Of course, that means we need to be able to call `show` on them directly, so `a` and `b` must have instances of Show.  Here's how that's done:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
   -- show :: Tree a b -> String
   show (Branch b ltree rtree) = {- some string -}
   show (Leaf a) = {- some string -}
```

Then it's just filling in the blanks with appropriate strings, such as:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
   -- show :: Tree a b -> String
   show (Branch b ltree rtree) = "(( " ++ show ltree ++ " ) <-- ( " ++ b ++ " ) --> ( " ++ show rtree ++ " ))"
   show (Leaf a) = "L " ++ show a
```